# A complex pulley system with one string

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

I was doing some pulley block problems, and one of the concepts used is tension in a massless string is same everywhere.

Also the tension on the string with which the pulley is connected is twice the tension of the string on either side of the pulley (since the pulley is also considered to be massless the net force on it must be zero)

Then I came across this question

[image: Question]

Let’s say I start from the string CB, and assume the tension to be $T$, then the tension in CE must also be T, therefore the tension in AE must also be T and the tension in AD must also be T then the tension at DB must also be T and the tension at BA must also be T.

But then the net force at pulley B will not be zero since there's a force of 2T upwards and only T downwards.

How is this possible?

Comment: Nice problem. Don't forget the pulleys have weight; don't forget they can and will accelerate if the net force is non-zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to assume that the statement that the pulleys are friction-less means that there is no friction between the strings and the pulleys.  Otherwise, we need to worry about the rotational inertia of the pulleys (which do have mass).  For pulleys (A) and (B):  mg + T – 2T = ma (taking down as +).  For pulley (C): mg – 2T = mA. If pulleys (A) and (B) each go down by one unit of distance, the supporting strings must extend by three units. Pulley (C) loses three units from above on the right side string, but gains one on the left. The net loss is two units (one on each side): A = -a.  Solving these equations yields three correct answers (assuming g = 10 N/kg).

Comment: But what is the correct answer A B C or D?

Comment: My original analysis was wrong.  Note the corrections in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have omitted two important factors:

1. Pulleys A, B and C are not massless - we are told they each have a mass of $1$ kg. So you have to take the weight of each pulley into account.
2. The net force on a pulley with non-zero mass is only zero if that pulley is in equilibrium i.e either stationary or moving with a constant velocity. But you don’t know that. Indeed, three of the given answer options suggest that the pulleys are *not* in equilibrium.